Problems with pyinstaller collect-data and sv_ttk
I am trying to create an executable using PyInstaller for my Python application, but I am encountering a ModuleNotFoundError for 'sv_ttk'. The application runs fine in my VS Code, but the error occurs only in the executable.
I tried including the sv_ttk module using the --hidden-import=sv-ttk  and adding --collect-data sv_ttk  to the pyinstaller options as suggested by other threads, I am getting this warning:
warning stating: "WARNING: collect_data_files - skipping data collection for module 'sv_ttk' as it is not a package.
This is my whole pyinstaller command:
pyinstaller.exe --onefile --windowed --hidden-import=sv-ttk --collect-data sv_ttk .\MyApp.py

I also made sure that sv-ttk is installed by running pip list

pyinstaller -F --collect-data sv_ttk ... works for me.

@acw1668 You mean I add the -F option? I tried it and it still gave me a warning of skipping data collection for module 'sv_ttk' as it is not a package

-F is the same as --onefile. Mine does not use --hidden-import.

Yeah I've tried without it too and I get the same thing. I'm not sure why it's not recognizing sv_ttk as a package. Although I can run it fine from vs code.

Did you use virtual environment? Are PyInstaller and sv-ttk installed in the same environment?
